# Когда никто не знает, какой препарат достался больному (?) исследуемый или плацебо

Tags: запятая

Когда никто не знает, какой препарат достался больному (?) исследуемый или плацебо.

Помогите, пожалуйста, подобрать знак препинания на месте вопроса.
Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

Когда никто не знает, какой препарат достался больному - исследуемый или плацебо?

Comment: А вопросительный-то зачем?

Answer (score 1):

По правилам, двоеточие, потому что "какой" можно считать обобщающим словом, но в данном случае однородные члены носят характер уточнения(какой именно препарат), поэтому  тире тоже возможно.

Comment: Людмила, а тут:

>Вам что намазать, меду или сгущенного молока?

Comment: Тогда уж ЧЕГО. А знак - и запятая, и тире, и двоеточие возможны, но тире всё равно лучше.

Comment: А, ну всё-таки запятая не исключается. А лучше - это уже днло вкуса.

В оригинале (сценарии мультика) - "что". И стилистически, думаю, так лучше. Правда там он к одному Пуху обращается...

Answer (score 0):

Это у вас вся фраза или её часть?
Впрочем, я лично бы поставил просто запятую. Тире здесь не требуется, но может быть как авторское.